# Convert Date to string using PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have date `2012/09/26`. I want to convert it to string using PHP.How do I fix this.Anyone help me please,Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by converting it to string??

Comment: That already is a string. Unless that happens to be the output of some fancy object - in which case it is probably already a string again?

Comment: var_dump("2012/09/26");  result = string(10) "2012/09/26"

Comment: Explain what do you mean by String? You mean a string without a specific format (in that case, Fluffeh answered your question) or you want to change it by 26th September 2012 for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is already a string, do you want to change format ?

```
 $date = '2012/09/26';
 echo date('l jS \of F Y', strtotime($date));
 // Wednesday 26th of September 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

/**
*   Converts the likes of '2008-12-22' to 'December 22, 2008'
*/

```
echo date(  "F j, Y", strtotime( $datetime_value ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly with http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date.php

```
// Shows like: Monday
echo date("l");
```